# How to achieve animation in ImageView like newsstand application header - Android

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I want to set Animation to images of in image view like in newsstand application and change image after  particular interval of time.

Please help its very important for me.

Answer (score 0):

for animating a view (image view included) i recommend [this library](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations)
set the animation time and when it ends change the image, full code for [the code snippet](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/daimajia/androidanimations/MyActivity.java)

```
rope = YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).duration(1000).playOn(mTarget);// after start,just click mTarget view, rope is not init 
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Techniques technique = (Techniques)view.getTag();
            rope =  YoYo.with(technique)
                        .duration(1200)
                        .interpolate(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
                        .withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            //change image here
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                            }
                        })
                        .playOn(mTarget);
        }
    });
```

Comment: set the custom animation you want instead of Techniques.FadeIn and change the image when animation ends with the time you specify  on .duration(seconds) 
@Android

Comment: how to create custom animation like that?

Comment: XML file , search for the animation as an XML file, I remember XDA forums are full of it